# NHibernate: Using value tables for optimization AND dynamic join

Tags: nhibernate

My situation is next: there are to entities with many-to-many relation, f.e. Products and Categories. Also, categories has hierachial structure, like a tree. There is need to select all products that depends to some concrete category with all its childs (branch). So, I use following sql statement to do that:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Products p
> WHERE p.ID IN (
>     SELECT DISTINCT pc.ProductID FROM ProductsCategories pc
>     INNER JOIN Categories c ON c.ID = pc.CategoryID
>     WHERE c.TLeft >= 1 AND c.TRight <= 33378
> )
> ```

But with big set of data this query executes very long and I found some solution to optimize it, look at here:

> ```
> DECLARE @CatProducts TABLE (
>     ProductID int NOT NULL
> )
>
> INSERT INTO @CatProducts
>     SELECT DISTINCT pc.ProductID FROM ProductsCategories pc
>     INNER JOIN Categories c ON c.ID = pc.CategoryID
>     WHERE c.TLeft >= 1 AND c.TRight <= 33378
>
> SELECT * FROM Products p
> INNER JOIN @CatProducts cp ON cp.ProductID = p.ID
> ```

This query executes very fast but I don't know how to do that with NHIbernate. Note, that I need use only ICriteria because of dynamic filtering\ordering.
If some one knows a solution for that, it will be fantastic. But I'll pleasure to any suggestions of course.

Thank you ahead,
Kostya

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple - adding index to ProductsCategories table for ProductId column fixed the problem.